# time series function not working due to possible indexing error?

Tags: r, function, csv, indexing, time-series

I am working with a folder of CSV files that will be analyzed via time-series. In order to perform the tests, I have decided to create a couple of functions that will pass through a for-loop to create a time-series analysis on specific variables in each file in the path.

Below my code can be separated into three sections: *the data import, the function creation, and it passing through the for-loop*.

The problem I am having is that I believe my function is improperly coded. When I run my code and initialize my time series function, I get an error saying the following: `'ts' object must have one or more observations`. When I try to plot my `data_frame` or the specific count of `csv_data`, the only option I have is to plot `csv_data$file_name`. This is a problem because I should get the option of `csv_data$placeholderName` instead.

IS there a problem with the way I have written my function? If so, how can I fix it? Are there any other problems you can see with my code?

*NOTE: many time-series objects will be made using this same method as to make it easier to analyze multiple files. For example, using the example data below, the function will create time-series objects using the 5 placeholderName variables.*

**CODE:**

```r
# retrieve data from the csv files from PATH
data <- list.files("/path of 1160 csv files", pattern = ".csv", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

# get list element for data
csv_data <- lapply(data, read.csv)

# Set the name of each list element to its respective file name.
# NOTE: full.names = FALSE to get only the file names, not the full path.
names(csv_data) <- gsub(".csv","", list.files("/path of 1160 csv files", pattern = ".csv", all.files = TRUE, full.names = FALSE), fixed = TRUE)
names(csv_data) <- gsub(", ", "-", names(csv_data), fixed = TRUE)

# Determine the amount of csvs in path
csv_length <- as.integer(length(csv_data))

# placeholderName is converted into time-series data. 
# Since dates were not mentioned in the Date format (shown as string)
# Thus general index were used (1 to 248)
# Declaring time series object

count <- 0
timeSeries <- function(count) {
  data_frame <- csv_data[count]
  data_frame[is.na(data_frame)] = 0
  placeholderName_ts = ts(data_frame$placeholderName, start = 1, end=248, frequency = 1)
  return(placeholderName_ts)
}

for (i in 1:csv_length) {
  count = i

  # time series creation
  timeSeries(i)
}
```

**EXAMPLE DATA:**

```
# placeholderName = phN
$`File-name-1`
       date            phN1   phN2      phN3     phN4         phN5
1   2020-02-15          0  8.331944  1.8722222 65.29108        NA
2   2020-02-16          1 15.045833 11.9569444 83.02963        NA
3   2020-02-17          1 15.090278 14.2013889 94.59667        NA
4   2020-02-18          5 20.806944 19.0736111 90.42332        NA
5   2020-02-19          1 13.134722 11.9388889 92.53200        NA
6   2020-02-20          0  9.240278  8.0916667 92.64821        NA
7   2020-02-21          2  5.838889 -0.8875000 64.58893        NA
```

Any more information, when requested will be added below:

- Edit_1: Each file (dataset) has the same structure: date, phN1, phN2, phN3, phN4, and phN5.

Comment: What is `placeholderName` ? Is it a fixed column in all the datasets?

Comment: I just changed the actual column names to placeholderName; hence, placeholder name. The actual columns are akin to temperature data if that helps. And yes, all the column names are the same in each dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this function -

```
timeSeries <- function(count) {
  data_frame <- csv_data[[count]]
  data_frame[is.na(data_frame)] = 0

  placeholderName_ts = ts(data_frame[[placeholderName]], 
                          start = 1, end=248, frequency = 1)
  return(placeholderName_ts)
}

result <- lapply(seq_len(csv_length), timeSeries)
```